For a given $m$, which is relatively prime to $p$, show there exists an $r$ such that $m$ divides $p^r-1.$
My question is: Suppose that we have an arbitrary natural number $m$ that is not divisible by the prime number $p.$ Then there exists an integer $r$ such that $m$ divides $p^r-1$.
Some help on this would be nice. As $\gcd(m,p) = 1$, I tried using Bezout's lemma to say that there is some $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ ms +1 = pt,$ and that we can write $t$ as $p^{k-1}n$ for some $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}, p\nmid n$, but that only gives me that $m \mid p^kn - 1.$

See the Lemma in the dupe, and see the 2nd dupe for generalizations. $\ \ $
